# Python time data does not match format

Tags: python, datetime

I have string date data with the following format:

```
4/16/15 23:50
```

When I try to convert into a datetime object:

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha2, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '4/16/15 23:50' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %H:%M'
```

According to this list:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior, I am using the right format. Where am I wrong?

Comment: 16 is an invalid month ....

Comment: month and day are reversed, there is no 16th month.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have month and day reversed:

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime(fecha2, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Comment: @ Alexander, nice catch. I thought I had double-checked everything..! I come from a country where typical format is d/m/y...

Answer (score 3):

Also very handy:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse("4/16/15 23:50")
```

Comment: no idea why someone downvoted this ... dateutil.parser is excellent I use it in 90% of the things where i need to parse dates

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is old but maybe it will help someone. I have faced recently similar issue where the date was actually correctly typed and it throwed the same error:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-05-02T14:27:56+00:00', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
```

error: time data '2018-05-02T14:27:56+00:00' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

The issue was that i was trying to run the python 3.7 code with python 3.6

Comment: thank you for this answer. It helped me realize that I was using the wrong format definition. datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"). I changed it to datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") and my code worked.